# moving from Joomla to Refinery

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms, refinery

I have an idea to move  site from PHP (Joomla + pure php) to Ruby on Rails (Refinery CMS). Old site has links with .html and .php extensions. Is there a way to keep old urls the same (I don't want to loose Google PageRank)? I tried to use  `config.use_custom_slugs = true` config with Refenery, but it drop '.' from url. (`store.php` becomes `storephp`, also `FAQ.html` becomes `faqhtml` ... etc ) 
Any help appreciated! Thanks.

In Rails I can do it next way

```
  #Application Controller
  def unknown_path
    #it works for all urls, here I can load page with needed slug
    render :text => "#{request.fullpath}"
  end

 #routes.rb
  match "*a", :to => "application#unknown_path" #in the end
```

And it will make any url working. So I could use custom slug if it exist or raise 404

But  CMS dosn't allow to create really custom slugs

**Why not 301**

Trying to explain: you get an external link coming to Page 1, then your Page 1 links internally to Page 2. Link to page 1 gets 1000 amount of page rank from the link. Link to page 2 gets 900 Therefore a link to 301 gets 1000 and the page that the 301 points to gets 900. So: 900 is better than it disappearing altogether, but I'm trying avoiding creating this situation. That how it works.

Comment: Looking at the debug logs, it looks like when I save a period is stripped out before the SQL update, but I've dug through Refinery's source, and couldn't find any reference to that stripping out in a before_save or anything. It may be caused by friendly_id gem stripping it out behind the scenes?

Comment: One other thing that it sounds like you have already decided against, but seems just as SEO friendly without sacrificing much ranking... Have you considered doing a 301 redirect via .htaccess file to the new (more SEO friendly) urls from refinery?

Comment: @creativereason, thanks for comments. I suggested 301 redirects but one of the main requirements is to keep old urls =(

Comment: maybe you do know any other rails CMS, which supports it out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

As per [my answer on Refinery's issue tracker](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/2322), where this was also asked, do you have to do this in Rails? What about rewriting the request before it even gets to Rails using proxy software such as [nginx with HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule)?

Comment: Hello @parndt, I updated my answer describing a way how to do this in rails.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when moving from wordpress to Comfortable Mexican Sofa ( another Rails CMS engine).

I ended up doing this in my routes.rb ( here is a sample of one of the redirects ( I don't have a lot - total of 15 redirects like that), which is generic Rails solution that can be used by RefineryCMS as well I think.

```
get '/2009/01/28/if-programming-languages-were-cars/', to: redirect('/blog/2009/01/if-programming-languages-were-cars-translated-into-russian')
```

This actually generates a proper redirect like so ( [impossible to see in the browser](http://gorbikoff.com/2009/01/28/if-programming-languages-were-cars/), but if you curl you'll see this:

```
curl http://gorbikoff.com/2009/01/28/if-programming-languages-were-cars/


<html>
  <body>
    You are being <a href="http://gorbikoff.com/blog/2009/01/if-programming-languages-were-cars-translated-into-russian">redirected</a>.
  </body>
</html>
```

And if we check headers - we see a proper 301 response:

```
curl -I http://gorbikoff.com/2009/01/28/if-programming-languages-were-cars/
```

returns

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 158
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://gorbikoff.com/blog/2009/01/if-programming-languages-were-cars-translated-into-russian
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: 9ec0d0b29e94dcc26433c3aad034eab1
X-Runtime: 0.002247
Date: Wed, 10 Jul 2013 15:11:22 GMT
X-Rack-Cache: miss
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.5
Server: nginx/1.4.1 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.5
```

**Specific to your case**

So that's the general approach. However for what you are trying to do ( redirect all urls that end in .php like yourdomain.com/store.php  to yourdomain.com/store) you should be able to do something like this. This assumes that you'll (map your new structure exactly, otherwise you may need to create a bunch of custom redirects like I mentioned in the beginning or do some Regex voodoo) :

**NON-Redirect Solution**

Don't redirect user, just render new page at the same address (it's a twist on solution you put in your question):

This is the only way that's more or less robust, if you don't want to do a redirect.

```
# routes.rb
# You don't need to match for .html - as they will be handled automatically by rails.
match '/*\.php', to: "application#php_path"

# application_controller.rb  
# This doesn't have to be application controller, 
# you may do this in your home_controller if you wish.
def php_path
  require 'open-uri'
  file = open "http://#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath.gsub!(/(.php)/,'')}"
  render :inline => file.read
end
```

**Redirect Solution:**
According to Google 301 is the preferred way https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en .

```
match '/*\.php', to: redirect {|params, request|
  "http://#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath.gsub(/(.php)/,'')}"
}
```

This will provide a Response Header Status Code 200. As far as the world is concerned you are serving PHP through passenger ( run curl -I against my site using this sample urls - these are just arbitrary params to illustrate my point)

```
curl -I http://gorbikoff.com/about?name=nick
curl -I http://gorbikoff.com/about.php?name=nick
```

You may need to fidget with this based on your specifics ( https vs http, etc, and maybe some virtual routes need to be address separately. Also remember about precedence in the route.rb ) but I think this might work for you.

**EDIT**
I just realized that this solution works out of the box in Comfortable Mexican Sofa ( it just ignores format ( .php is treated same way .html would be treated). However I tried my solutions in non-cms based rails 3 project I have ( it's not public) and my solution still holds with slight change - I just fixed it (sorry for the confusion).

I suggest also to check official guide at (I'm assuming you are on Rails 3.2.13 since RefinderyCMS doesn't support Rails 4 officially yet)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/routing.html#redirection

And check out Rails API

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html#method-i-redirect

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for response, but I won't to use 301 redirect because of loosing Google PAge rank for each such page.

Comment: Give me a few mins, I think I came up with a solution that might work for you

Comment: @Fivell Check out my updated answer, let me know if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: @Fivell I just updated my answer again - I remember reading that 301 was preferable. I was looking for this link (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en)